# Add right constraint to two labels with variable width

Tags: swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have two UILabels next to each other in the view where I will show comments to a post, one for the username and one for the timestamp. I convert the timestamp to an easy format like "1h" for one hour ago, "22m" for 22 minutes ago etc.

These are my two labels:

```
var usernameLabel: UILabel = {

    let usernameLabel = UILabel()
    usernameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    usernameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    usernameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    usernameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    usernameLabel.text = "Username"
    usernameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    usernameLabel.isExclusiveTouch = false
    usernameLabel.backgroundColor = .green

    return usernameLabel

}()

var commentDateLabel: UILabel = {

    let commentDateLabel = UILabel()
    commentDateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    commentDateLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    commentDateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    commentDateLabel.backgroundColor = .red

    return commentDateLabel

}()
```

I add constraints to both of them to make sure they fit inside my view, like this:

```
commentDateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
commentDateLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

usernameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePictureImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
```

The problem I'm facing is, the date is aligned on the far right and the username takes up the entire width. I would like it different - where the label of the username is just as wide as needed and the date taking up the entire space that's left.

[image: current situation]

In other words: I want the green label to shorten to just fit the text and the red label to take up the entire width that's left, so both of them are next to each other but when a username is too long it will truncate and still show the entire date label. How would I go about this?

Comment: If it is a `UILabel`, just don't set the `rightAnchor`. The label will resize itself to fit the content it has.

Comment: What I was thinking indeed. But then how would I make sure to add a constant of 8px between both labels? I definitely want to add a rightAnchor to the date label as it should always be on the far right when the username is too long. Then, if I delete the rightAnchor of the usernameLabel (where it is equal to the commentDateLabel with a constant of 8), the username is aligned on the left and the date on the right, but both are fitted to its size, just not next to each other..

Comment: The right anchor would still exist where the label ends, so your constraints will still work. Just remove the right anchor for the label.

Comment: You could also use a stackView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set

> contentHuggingPriority

to `usernameLabel` to be higher than the other , also set

> contentCompressionResistance

to `commentDateLabel` to be higher

Comment: Whoa. That's precisely what I was looking for, I think! That works like a charm. Thank you!